# Leaflet vs Mapbox GL JS: JavaScript libraries comparison

Tags: javascript, leaflet, performance, mapbox

I would like to do a comparison of **Leaflet.js** and **Mapbox GL.js** libraries. Therefore I would like to ask if you have some ideas of which parameters should I test.

In my initial research I decided to go with the following:

---

**Learning aspects**

- *Learning curve*.
- *Frequency of updates*
- *Community support*
- *Documentation*

---

**Technical aspects**

- *Performance* : here I would like to compare for instance data consumption and loading times. (Does anybody know how to measure this in browsers?)
- *Interoperability* : related with data format compatibility.
- *Compatibility* : browser compatibility.
- Raster and vector tiles.

---

Apart from my list I would like to know if you guys have any idea of what else can be compared in the context of mapping social related stuff (see the web apps at the end) for non-expert users with backgrounds different than computer science or geoinformatics.

The two web apps on which my question is based can be found here:

- [Leaflet](https://cccruzr.github.io/colmigrationleaflet/)
- [Mapbox GL JS](https://cccruzr.github.io/colmigrationmapbox/)

Answer (score 3):

They are going to very similar is terms of all the aspects you list because [Leaflet forms the basis of Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-leaflet/).  Mapbox may offer some additional convenience, but if you can do it in one, you can do it in the other.  Mapbox GL is a GL version of Mapbox so will feel very similar again.  However, see this thread for more information on the [differences between Mapbox vanilla and GL].[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069753/mapbox-gl-js-vs-mapbox-js)

The documentation for Mapbox/GL and Leaflet is fairly comprehensive and both have active communities.